# How to call a javascript function inside kendo grid column template with razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, grid

I have implemented a Kendo Grid with MVC4 and Razor syntax.  This grid displays log entries from a database table.  The LogText column contains text with Windows newline characters.  I am trying to replace those newline characters with line break tags.  To do this, I have created a javascript function that I am wanting to call from a column template.  The grid uses server binding.  I cannot seem to find the correct syntax to make a javascript call from within the template.  I have seen many examples, but none seem to be with the Razor syntax.  I hope someone can help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Core.Models.ShipmentLog>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShipmentLog";
}

<h2>ShipmentLog</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("ShipmentLogGrid")
    .Columns(columns=>
    {
        columns.Bound(bl => bl.UserName);
        columns.Bound(bl => bl.LogTime);
        columns.Bound(bl => bl.LogType);
        columns.Bound(bl => bl.LogText).Width(600).Encoded(false).Template(#=  GetHtmlNewLinesString(@item.LogText) #);

    })

)

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getHtmlNewLinesString(text) {
        return text.replace('\n/g', '<br />');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: look at the rendered code.  I believe it is going to render as a table.  I would just put a .each in the document ready that will loop through the table rows and run your function

Comment: Thanks Matt. I confess to being a novice when it comes to client side programming with javascript.  I may have to do what you suggest.  I was hoping however, to be able to accomplish this from inside the Kendo column template.  There are examples on the web for when the grid is implemented inside javascript, but not for RAZOR.  Unfortunately, everything I have tried to get this call to work in the Template never makes the call to the function.  Again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved without javascript, but for learning on how to use templates refer to @C Sharper's answer.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#template

```
columns.Bound(bl => bl.LogText)
       .Template(@<text>@item.LogText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
       .Width(600)
       .Encoded(false);
```

Comment: Your answer set me on the right path.  Thanks.  However, I had to wrap it with an @Html.Raw even with the .Encoded(false).  What ended up working was:  `columns.Bound(bl => bl.LogText).Template(@<text>@Html.Raw(@item.LogText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))</text>).Width(600).Encoded(false);`

Comment: Even though this worked, I would still like to know the syntax for executing a javascript function inside the .Template().  I have scoured the web and cannot find the specific syntax.  Is this because what is contained in .Template() is server side code?  I tried .ClientTemplate(), but I think it was not working because I was using server binding for my datasource.  Is that correct?  Sorry for all the questions, but I am new to this stuff.

Answer (score 5):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Details")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.SubSystemOrderId).Title("Subsys #");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Description).Title("Description").Template(@<text><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="return window.top.DisplayExternalOrderDetails('@item.SubSystemOrderId', '@item.OrderDetailTypeId', '@item.ProposalId', '@ViewBag.MyOpExUser', '@ViewBag.selectedOpportunityId')">@item.Description</a></text>);
    columns.Bound(m => m.SubSystemStatusName).Title("Status");
    columns.Bound(m => m.GrossRevenue).Title("Gross Revenue").Format("{0:c}");
    columns.Bound(m => m.IncludeInForecast).Title("Include In Forecast").Template(m=>m.IncludeInForecast ? "Yes" : "No");
    columns.Bound(m => m.ProposalId).Title("Proposal Id").Visible(false);

})
)
```

another example

```
columns.Bound(m => m.OpportunityName).Title("Opportunity Name").ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick=\"return openMSDynamicsWindow('#= OpportunityUrl #');\">#= OpportunityName #</a>").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-link" });
```

You'll see im passing into the function `'#= OpportunityUrl #'`. That's how you can grab values off of the model.
  `#= OpportunityName #` will be the the link text.

This is a more Complex example, you can really do anything you want. Just getting the string based crap to work is a real pain

```
columns.Bound(m => m.Dollars).Title("").ClientTemplate(
          "# if (Dollars == null) { #" +
          "" +
          "# } else if (Dollars == 0) { #" +
          "<div>#= kendo.toString(Dollars, 'c') #</div>" +
          "# } else if (Count > 0) { #" +
          "<a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick=\"return window.top.openOrderDetails('#= Count #','#= Type #','#= DetailId #','#= OrderId #','#= User #','#= SelectedId #');\">#= kendo.toString(Dollars, 'c') #</a>" +
          "# } #"
          )
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Your first example was a crystal oasis in a desert of nothingness! Worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to someone. Im using this to build a unique id inside the textbox. In addition to that you could easily write in an onclick or on blur event. Then just pass in with it the element ID.

```
 Html.Kendo().Grid((List<RadCarePlus.V2.Web.Models.Facilities>) ViewData["FacilitiesList"])
.Name("Facilities")
.Columns(columns =>
{   int i = 0;
    columns.Bound(c => c.ProviderID).Title("Provider Number").Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;" });
    columns.Bound(c => c.NPI).Title("NPI").Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;" });
    columns.Bound(c => c.ProviderFirstName).Template(c => c.ProviderFirstName + " " + c.ProviderLastName).Title("Provider Name").Width(140).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: underline;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;" });
    columns.Bound(c => c.AddressLine1).Template(c => c.AddressLine1 + " " + c.AddressLine2 + "<BR>" + c.City + " " + c.State + " " + c.Zipcode).Title("Address").Width(140).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left; white-space: nowrap;" });
    columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Template(c => "<input type='text' name='AdminEmail' id='" + (i = i + 1) + "' value='" + c.Email + "'> ").Title("Administrator").Width(140).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: underline;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; white-space: nowrap;" });          
})
.Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().PageSize(5)
)
```